# Does the file protocol file:// in a url affect playback of .FLV's

Tags: video, html, flash

I'm having some trouble with the playback of videos on a local site. At the moment it's been accessing purely through a link to the HTML assets on a mapped network drive.

The videos are FLV and are embedded in a SWFplayer so the code works fine but when playing back through the browser, the player loads but the videos don't.

I tested them OK on a local XAMPP server which ruled out the browser settings (I think) so could the use of the file:// protocol in the URL effect playback ?

Any additional thoughts or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that does come across a similar issue, later instances of IE and other main browsers detect issues with the File:// protocol when playing back videos from HTML files. You can either host in or XAMPP, IIS or an equivalent - worked for me no problem